# AngularJS - utilizing serivce/controller model to create global timer for all clients

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, web-applications

I am fairly new to AngularJS and although I normally prefer to work through my problems, I feel as though I am missing a fundamental concept of client/server programming with AngularJS.

Currently I am trying to just get a very basic application working as a proof of concept for myself. In this application I want to have a timer that simply counts down from a set time (say in this example 2 minutes) and then restart. While I have the timer logic working, I run into trouble when attempting to have the timer be global so that any client who connects, will see the same  countdown as the user who started it.

From initial research, I thought that the best way to do this would be through a service as seen below:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('countdownTimer', []);


myApp.service('timerService',['$http', function($http){
 var time = 180;
 
 return {
  getTime: getTime,
  setTime: setTime
 };
 
 function getTime(){
  return  time;
 }
 function setTime(value){
  time = value;
 }
}]);

myApp.controller('CounterController', ['$timeout','$scope', 'timerService', function($timeout, $scope, timerService){
 /**$scope.counter = 180;
 **/
 var date = new Date(null);
 date.setSeconds(timerService.getTime());
 $scope.time_format = date.toISOString().substr(14,5);
 
 
 $scope.onTimeout = function() {
  timerService.setTime(timerService.getTime()-1);
  var date = new Date(null);

  date.setSeconds(timerService.getTime());
  $scope.time_format = date.toISOString().substr(14,5);
  if (timerService.getTime() > 0){
   mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
   
  }
  else{
   
   //$scope.counter = 180;
   timerService.setTime(180);
   date.setSeconds(timerService.getTime());
   mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
  }
 }
 $scope.start = function(){
  var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000); 
 }
 
 $scope.stop = function(){
  $timeout.cancel(mytimeout);
 }
 
 
}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title> Example </title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 
</head>
 
<body data-ng-app="countdownTimer">
 <div data-ng-controller="CounterController">
  {{time_format}}
  <button data-ng-click="stop()">Pause</button>
  <button data-ng-click="start()">Start</button>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

However, when I open multiple tabs on a browser and connect to this they all start at different locations instead of one globally controlled timer. I am sure this is very obvious but as someone new to angular/web development I am at a loss.

Comment: If you expect the timer to be accessible from multiple clients and stay in sync, you need to have the timer managed on the server and then have the clients poll it for the remaining time (or use a websocket to have the server tell the clients how much time is remaining).

Answer (score 0):

This should be controled in your service

```
var date = new Date(null);
```

Update your service as

```
   myApp.service('timerService',['$http', function($http){
    var time = 180;


    this.getTime = function(){
        return  time;
    }
    this.setTime = function(value){
        time = value;
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I have updated my service as you have suggested. However I still notice that it appears to be two separate instances of the timer. I open one tab and start it, followed by a second app and it appears they are both running independently instead of concurrently. Suggestions?

Comment: angular service returns a single instance of the service function so you might have some kind of different problem. Can you share it with plunkr ?

Comment: Again, the timer works well. Its just that it works in an instanced manner. If I have two separate sessions of Firefox open and go to the file they both run separate timers instead of both tracking the same values.

Answer (score 0):

Using a session, cookie or localStorage is three possibilities (be aware of the bad practice).
If you have some kind of a user i would map the timer to the session and than let a server handle the mapping and fetching of the timer for the client. Then you could have it secure and the user would have the same timer no matter what browser or computer he is using.